# Checkbox inside combobox in C#

Tags: checkbox, combobox

I got a field called hobby .. the user may have multiple hobby .
I want to make a combobox of hobby but with multiple choice ... so I can choose more the one option .

I think about make combobox with checkbox .

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Use checkedListbox control provided by winforms.